# Could not find method implementation() error in Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have this big error:

```
Build file 'build.gradle' line: 56

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'FireKidsGame-master'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'FireKidsGame-master'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:723)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:150)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:226)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:164)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:90)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMissingMethodExecutionFailed.<init>(AbstractDynamicObject.java:190)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:184)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:86)
    at build_72crvm3zpi0rknx6wwj80inv3$_run_closure3$_closure13.doCall(E:\Freelancer\FireKidsGame-master\build.gradle:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.dependencies(DefaultProject.java:1230)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:484)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:56)
    at build_72crvm3zpi0rknx6wwj80inv3$_run_closure3.doCall(E:\Freelancer\FireKidsGame-master\build.gradle:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions.with(Actions.java:251)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator$2.run(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.lambda$runProjectConfigureAction$0(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.runProjectConfigureAction(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.project(BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.project(DefaultProject.java:1197)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:484)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:135)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.invokeMethod(BasicScript.java:84)
    at build_72crvm3zpi0rknx6wwj80inv3.run(E:\Freelancer\FireKidsGame-master\build.gradle:49)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 140 more
```

Here is build.gardle file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Fire Kids Game"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.3'
        roboVMVersion = '2.1.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
        gdxPayVersion = '0.11.2'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {

    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android:$gdxPayVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android-googleplay:${gdxPayVersion}@aar"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-client:$gdxPayVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-client:$gdxPayVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

And here is gradle-wrapper.properities:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-all.zip

And I don`t know where is mistake. If you need more info, write in comment what you need. Also I using 2020.3.1 version of Android Studio.

Comment: Please share your settings.gradle file along with the folder structure where this `core` folder is

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I no longer do this project.